# Distribute data for hyperparameter optimization in pytorch

Tags: database, neural-network, pytorch, distributed-computing, pytorch-lightning

### Question

How do I set up hyperparameter optimization on the same dataset on multiple servers (or containers) without duplicated data preprocessing?

The *possible solution* feels useful and like a common task, but I fear reimplementing existing code. Therefore, what is the framework I am searching for, or if there are multiple: What is the keyword I am missing?

### Setting the scene

- I built a package using neural networks for classification and want hyperparameter optimization.
- I used `pytorch-lightning` and `PyTorch Geometric` combined with `hydra`
- I have multiple servers on-premise with multiple GPUs each
- Data preprocessing takes a fair amount of time
- Data fits into each single GPU
- Hyperparameters are network architecture but also variants of data preprocessing

#### Possible solution?

Usually, `torch datasets`:

1. download the raw dataset
2. preprocess it
3. are stored or loaded in memory to be fed into the neural network.

Now that feels inefficient when I want to optimize hyperparameters because this would have to be done at least on every server, if not even inside every container instance. Therefore I feel the following would be optimal:

1. Preprocess the raw dataset on one server instance with set `i` of `preproc-hparams`
2. Distribute *the preprocessed* data to all other servers
3. Test all hyperparameters
4. Go to 1. with the next set of `preproc-hparams`

Comment: Your proposed solution sounds to me like the way to go. Whats wrong with it? If the dataset isn't too large i would simply copy it to the target machine (or download it from the central server). There are also shared filesystems which might be helpful if you don't want initial download. I once used sshfs to completely avoid storing anything on the server and it worked surprisingly well (over lan and only one GPU)

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, it just feels like a "custom-built" solution coding that by myself when I assumed there is an out-of-the-box principle already doing that :)